# How do you make it run until y reaches 20

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

#I'm trying to print, whatever results the program suppose to print, 20 times
#but whenever I print it, it only print once. How do I make the while loop run for 20 continuous #times?

```
poke_list=[]
def z(y=20):
    x= simulate_pokemon_hunt()
    tryy=0
    while y==20:
        if x=="":
            print("Hunt was failed")
            y+=1
            tryy+=1
        else:
            poke_list.append(x)
            print("You caught a","".join(poke_list),"!")
            y+=1
            tryy+=1
    print("".join(poke_list).split())
pokemon_hunt(y=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `while y <= 20:`

When you say `while y == 20` if becomes true only once, i.e, when y ==20.

Also set the initial value of y = 0

```
poke_list=[]
def z(y=20):
    inc = 0
    x= simulate_pokemon_hunt()
    tryy=0
    while inc <= 20:
        if x=="":
            print("Hunt was failed")
            inc += 1
            y += 1
            tryy+=1
        else:
            poke_list.append(x)
            print("You caught a","".join(poke_list),"!")
            inc += 1
            y+=1
            tryy+=1
    print("".join(poke_list).split())
pokemon_hunt(y=20)
```

Comment: I need the y value to be 20 for the assignment purpose, also I tried y<=20 yet it ran only once ‍♂️

Comment: Then create another variable (e.g, x) and set that to 0 and then use while x <= 20 and also increment x inside the while loop

Comment: edited my answer. I used the variable inc

Comment: Hi,I'm not a beginner lol I recently started learning python again but your code does only print one word for 20 time. Can you suggest how I can make it so each time a new pokemon is caught?

Comment: Is the output supposed to be print("".join(poke_list).split()) because if it is it is outside of the scope of the while loop and thus will only run once the while loop is over.

Comment: it is inside of the loop

Comment: Sorry but it seemed that you have problem with basic while loop.